# Tying MembershipUser and Web.Profile together for newly created users

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership, profile, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3. I am using what essentially came with for free in the Visual Studio project template for an MVC project with the "Internet Application" option. Basically this brings in Forms authentication and provides some basic elements to manage user login and stuff.

I am also using the web profiles stuff with this to store some custom fields. Everything was going great. I use `SuperFunProfile` as a wrapper around the `Profile` instance to make it easier to get at profile properties.

Until I wanted to set a property of a Profile right away after signing the user up.

The problem I can't solve is that `this.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Profile` contains the profile for the anonymous user. How can I get a new profile for the user now that he should be signed up and signed in?

```
    public ActionResult SignUp(SignUpModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = this.MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                this.FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                var profile = new SuperFunProfile(this.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Profile);
                profile.DisplayName = model.UserName;
                profile.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }
```

I poked around Membership and Web.Profile, but I am not seeing anything that looks like it will get me closer to my goal.

Maybe I should just create a ProfileModel that I store myself into the DB rather than using Web.Profile? I could key that on `MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey` which would make it easier to create a ProfileModel at sign up, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [MigrateAnonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemodule.migrateanonymous.aspxauthenticated.) event.

> When users log in (that is, when they
>   stop being anonymous users), the
>   MigrateAnonymous event is raised. You
>   can handle this event to migrate
>   information from the user's anonymous
>   identity to the new authenticated
>   identity, if necessary. The following
>   code example shows how to migrate
>   information when a user is
>   authenticated.

In your global.asax use something like

```
public void Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous(object sender, ProfileMigrateEventArgs args)
{
  ProfileCommon anonymousProfile = Profile.GetProfile(args.AnonymousID);

  Profile.ZipCode = anonymousProfile.ZipCode; //Your custom property
  Profile.CityAndState = anonymousProfile.CityAndState;//Your custom property
  Profile.StockSymbols = anonymousProfile.StockSymbols;//Your custom property

  ////////
  // Delete the anonymous profile. If the anonymous ID is not 
  // needed in the rest of the site, remove the anonymous cookie.

  ProfileManager.DeleteProfile(args.AnonymousID);
  AnonymousIdentificationModule.ClearAnonymousIdentifier(); 

  // Delete the user row that was created for the anonymous user.
  Membership.DeleteUser(args.AnonymousID, true);

}
```

Comment: Good information. However, I don't actually want to migrate the settings from the anonymous profile. I want to create new profile settings from the newly signed up and signed in MembershipUser instance for the newly signed up user.

Comment: @mcl: Can't you still use this event to clear/delete anonymous profile?I am not sure about it but maybe you need to clear it, so you can see the logged in user profile

Comment: Indeed, this event works for this. Although it seems to get fired a *lot* so I ended up doing some filtering by URL/path to determine if this is really an event I need to handle. Thanks!